# Azure Linux remove and add another disk

Tags: linux, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I had a need to increase the disk space, for my Linux azure, we attached a new empty disk and followed the steps here http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-how-to-attach-disk , the only difference is that the newly added deviceid was not found in /var/log/messages.

Now I need to add another disk, and we attached another disk, the problem is that for doing the first step of fdisk

```
sudo fdisk /dev/sdc
```

I have no idea where the recent disk is attached, total clueless, also what are the steps if i want to remove a disk altogether, I know umount will unmount a disk, but that doesn't neccessarily takes off the device from the instance, i want a total detachment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out - the additional SCSI disks added are started from /dev/sda, /dev/sdb , /dev/sdc, /dev/sdd, /dev/sde.... The reason why the MS tutorial talks about /dev/sdc is because its the 3rd disk in the system, 1st your root volume, second your ephemeral temp storage, and this is your 3rd one, now as the /dev/sdc is not good enough for you and you want to remove it

1. Remove entry from /etc/fstab file
2. umount /datadrive

you can now remove the attached disk from your Azure console.

Lets say that sdc is still there and you want to add another, just attach from the azure console, and do the same steps as given in http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-how-to-attach-disk/#initializeinlinux  the only diff is that the another disk would be at /dev/sdd places where you make a partitions at /dev/sdc1 will become /dev/sdd1  that's pretty much about it.

References

1. http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialAdditionalHardDrive.html
2. http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-how-to-attach-disk/#initializeinlinux

Answer (score 0):

When adding more than one disk, it will also become important to start using uuid in fstab. Search for uuid in [this article](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-how-to-attach-disk/) for more.